# What are the benefits of direct sun viewing spectrometer over a backscatter measuring spectrometer to quantify trace gases in the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science, spectroscopy

I am using a Pandora spectrometer and a MAX-DOAS spectrometer to quantify the amount of formaldehyde (HCHO) present in the troposphere and stratosphere in Fairbanks, Alaska. Both the spectrometers use the Lambert-Beer's law for quantifying the amount of HCHO in the air by using different viewing geometries. I want to know what role does the view geometry play in the working of these spectrometers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major advantage of a direct Sun measurement is that you get a very high signal to noise ratio.  The background Sun is very, very bright.  And when the Sun is close to the horizon, you get a long optical path for an even better signal to noise ratio.  Like this, you can measure molecular species that are impossible to detect using any other passive method.

The disadvantage of a direct Sun measurement is that you need a direct view of the Sun, and you can only measure in the direction of the Sun.  Although the Sun is often close to the horizon in Fairbanks, the climate is relatively cloudy so quite often you cannot view the Sun.  But for stratospheric measurements with an indirect Sun measurement, any piece of blue sky should do.  So those measurements will be a lot more frequent, which can partially offset the worse signal-to-noise ratio if your signal is relatively constant.  I don't know enough about formaldehyde to tell you whether that is the case here.